# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string while calling shell in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins I'm calling a python script to do some magic actions. The pipeline is in production state for some time now and suddenly for one developer branch I'm getting

```
Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

constanly this Error in Jenkins.

The causing snippet seems to be this one:

```
sh """
        . .venv/bin/activate
        python3 -m some_python_package.some_sub_package.script --stage update_something \
            --api PROD '$SOME_ID' '$SOME_TOKEN' --user_id ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME} --file_list ${validFilePath} 2>&1 | tee output/log.txt
"""
```

I already tried different escaping methods, but also this one did not help, same error message remains:

```
sh """
        . .venv/bin/activate
        python3 -m some_python_package.some_sub_package.script --stage update_something \
            --api PROD \'$SOME_ID\' \'$SOME_TOKEN\' --user_id ${env.CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME} --file_list ${validFilePath} 2>&1 | tee output/log.txt
"""
```

Comment: The actual error may *precede* the location where the error is finally reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a very stupid case. As mentioned by @pmod one of the variables in file_list had a ' contained in a string, which messed up the shell comand...
So the shell comand in the Jenkins file was correct, but I have to take care that the input values are correct as well in future

Comment: great that you solved it, and that my comment helped :)  don't know why question -1, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know variables to shell should be passed with using ${XX}, e.g.

```
 ... ${SOME_ID} ..
```

but it doesn't look safe to pass token this way, I think you should pass it through environment variable

Comment: I just changed it, but it has no impact on the pipeline run - still showing the unterminated quoted string error. Regarding safely storing API token, yes I agree!

Comment: @Scf_suedbaden ok, then it's also possible that "missing quote" appear after variables' expansion, e.g. CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME or validFilePath, try with some good default values to eliminate this case